# how to set the order of elements with attributes in XSD

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

is it possible to define the order of elements?

**example**
I have the following XML file

```
<input>
   <action no="1" type="xyz"/>
   <action no="2" type="abc"/>
   <action no="3" type="ddd"/>
</input>
```

**An XSD check should fail when**

- attribute no does not start at 1
- the attributes are not ordered 1, 2, 3 ...
- there are numbers missing like 1, 3, 4

**Thats my current XSD**

```
<complexType name="action">
    <attribute name="no" use="required">
        <simpleType>
            <restriction base="int">
                <minInclusive value="1"></minInclusive>
                <maxInclusive value="99"></maxInclusive>
                <whiteSpace value="collapse"></whiteSpace>
            </restriction>
        </simpleType>
    </attribute>
    <attribute name="type" type="string"></attribute>
</complexType>

<complexType name="input">
    <sequence>
        <element name="action" type="tns:action"></element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSD 1.1 you could use an assertion:

```
 <xs:element name="input">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="action"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert id="sequence-of-no-values" test="every $i in 1 to count(action) satisfies $i eq action[$i]/@no"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```